# Is is legal to modify a nonconst pointer through a const one like this?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following function:

```
void f(int const* p)
{
    *const_cast<int*>(id(p)) = 0;
}
```

Is this a legal thing to do assuming `f` always gets an `int*` as a parameter?
I'm not asking if it's a good thing to do, I just want a strictly formal answer.

What worries me a little is that if you can do this, the optimizer has a way harder job utilizing consts. Consider a more convoluted example:

```
// identity, always returns what it gets
uintptr_t id(uintptr_t p)
{
    static unsigned int const ar[5] {0x12345678, 0x87654321, 0x02468ACE, 0xECA86420, 0x88888888};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        p ^= ar[2*i % 5];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        p ^= ar[3*i % 5];

    return p;
}

void f(int const* p)
{
    uintptr_t q = id(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p));
    *reinterpret_cast<int*>(q) = 0;
}
```

Would this be legal too? And if not, would changing the parameter to `int* p` make it legal?

Comment: It's OK to modify modifyable objects. It doesn't matter how you do this (so a `const_cast` is in principle not a problem). What worries me more is the `id` function. There are rules as to what constitutes a valid pointer, and I can't immediately see whether `id` preserves that validity.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: `id` always returns the same number it gets. (id stands for identity, also don't mind the constants, they could be anything)

Comment: @KerrekSB The associativity `^` gives that the code is equivalent to `p ^= ar[0]^ar[2]^ar[4]^ar[1]^ar[3]; /* 1st loop/* p ^= ar[0]^ar[3]^ar[1]^ar[4]^ar[2]; /* 2nd loop*/`, that is, `p ^= ar[0]^ar[2]^ar[4]^ar[1]^ar[3]^ar[0]^ar[3]^ar[1]^ar[4]^ar[2];`. The commutativity of `^` implies the latter is equivalent to `p ^= ar[0]^ar[0]^ar[1]^ar[1]^ar[2]^ar[2]^ar[3]^ar[3]^ar[4]^ar[4];`, that is, `p ^= 0^0^0^0^0;`. Since `x ^ 0 = x` for all `x`, `p` is left unchanged. I guess the OP is testing whether the optimizer can figure this out and remove the uneeded code (leaving only the `return p;` statement).

Comment: @Cassio Neri: Quite the opposite. I'm making sure the optimizer won't remove that. Also, any prime greater than 5 would do too, because if it's a prime, the indexes can't repeat, so it has to run through all indexes exactly once (and it doesn't matter in what order, as you posted).

Comment: Why would you not want that code to be removed, if it does nothing? I personally would love it if the compiler would notice and remove any code that "does nothing" :)

Comment: @rozina: Because I wanted to make the compiler feel like it doesn't know what the result is, so it has to think it's another variable. (of course you wouldn't write a code like this, I just wanted to know the limits of the language)

Comment: @user2345215 You probably know that but, more generally, if `m` and `n` are coprimes, then `m*i % n != m*j % n` for all `i != j` in `{0, ..., n - 1}`. Whether the code can be optimized away or not is a "compiler feature" rather than a language limit. The language itself allows this optimization (under the so called *as-if rule*). I believe (to be checked) that you can be sure the code will not be optimized away by declaring `uintptr_t id(volatile uintptr_t p)`. In this case, you don't need to obfuscate your code that much and even the assignment `p = p;` would be performed at runtime.

Comment: @Cassio Neri: Yeah I know, also I just checked my code and it actually almost got optimized away (reduced to `xor eax,F337733F; xor eax,F337733F` :)) Changing the constants to something depending on the parameter would solve it, but I agree your `volatile` method is much simpler.

Comment: I suspect @KerrekSB is talking about "safely derived" pointers, not "same number".

Comment: I would look into the strict aliasing rules, and if they apply to `const` vs non-`const`: can the compiler ignore a modification of a variable modified via pointer-to-non-`const` when reading from the pointer-to-`const` like it could for non-cv type pointer differences?

Comment: @Yakk: That's what I was worried about. But before asking this question, I read the section about `const_cast` in the standard and even though I didn't fully understand it, I believed I can modify it like that. I posted this question to be completely sure and the answer seems to confirm it. But thanks for commenting. I want to hear as many opinions on this as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's legal if the value pointed to is actually non-const, that's why we've got `const_cast` in the first place. It's undefined if the value is actually constant and you cast the `const` away.

if `f` is always being given a `int*` then why not just declare `f` to take a non-const? Alternativly you could provide an overload:

```
void f(int const* a)
void f(int *a)
```

So that the compiler will call the correct version and the user will see what your intentions are. Calling the first version and having it change the value may be a surprise to anyone calling `f`.

Comment: Because I wanted to know the limits of the optimizer. Is `g` OK too then?

Comment: When you use `reinterpret_cast` you're basically telling the compiler to stop caring as you know best, so yes! Why do you cast to a `uintptr_t` and then to an `int*` ?

Comment: @user2345215 - true, but in `g` you're not doing xor.

Comment: Well, as I'm apparently not getting other opinions, I'd like to accept this. But you probably misread the `g` function, there's a whole bunch of `xor`s applied to the argument (although it's ultimately preserved). I just want to know you are sure the `g` is legal too.

Comment: In the code you've posted you don't call the `g` function, so it's hard for me to comment on anything other than what you've posted!

Comment: Ah, just assume it's like `f`. Meaning whenever I call it, I'm passing `int*` actually.

Comment: You should really just post the code for `g` so that it makes the question and answers complete. But yes, it's legal to cast away the const (however you do it) as long as the actual item pointed to is not const in the first place. If it is const then you're in undefined territory.

Comment: @Sean: Casting away the `const` is _always_ valid. Modifying an immutable object (including if you achieved that by first casting away the `const`) is not.